# Are bitwise operations slower in multi-thread apps?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted some opinion on bitwise operations in multi-threaded apps. On one side I know that bitwise operations are very fast, but I've also heard that it forces the app to use a single-thread approach when processing the request that could lead to actual performance decrease.

Consider the following code:

```
public void Swap() {
   var tempObject = new Vector2( y, x);
   this.x = tempObject.x;
   this.y = tempObject.y;
}
```

A couple of things bother me here. First - I have to create a new object. An object that would need to be disposed of. Secondly, I feel that passing `y` and then `x` to the constructor could make the programmer looking at this code wonder at first if there's a typo. Although that code is very minimalistic, but you get the idea.

I wanted to refactor the same method to look like this:

```
public void Swap() {
    this.x ^= this.y;
    this.y ^= this.x;
    this.x ^= this.y;
}
```

The good thing is that there's no temporary variable (although I know Unity handles those pretty well without starting a huge garbage-collection process). Also it should be faster. The cost is that the method is less readable; indeed not every programmer knows bitwise commands and what they do, although it should be pretty obvious from the method's name.

But is it really faster? Or am I just stuck in the past and the better way is to actually create a temporary variable to get better performance?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new object or do fancy binary arithmetic to swap two variables.

```
public void Swap() 
{
   var temp = x;
   x = y;
   y = x;
}
```

Here you have 0 allocation. The `temp` value is just pushed on the stack, which puts no stress on the garbage collector.

Comment: The particular example isn't important. The question in general is - is bitwise going to give a boost in performance-critical code or slow things down? Or maybe no effect at all (e.g. in cases where the compiler can clearly see what's happening and optimize it for you).

Comment: @コルパコフアレクセイ It depends? In this case there's no point in using bitwise operations. You're reading the fields six times, doing three operations, and writing them three times, where you could do just two reads and two writes. But yes, bitwise operations can speed up some codes, especially when it allows to avoid branching